# I receive error while installing php 7 on redhat 7

Tags: rhel, software-installation, openssl, php7

I'm trying to install php 7 with below script:

```
yum -y install php php-mysql php-pecl-zip php-xml php-mbstring php-gd
```

but I receive below error:

```
Error: Package: php-7.0.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-7.0.26-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I installed openssl 1.0.2 but I receive it again.

How can I install php 7 successfully?

Comment: Are you using the official repos for this, or have you added third party repos?

Answer (score 0):

With this command `yum install php php-mysql php-pecl-zip php-xml php-mbstring php-gd` install `php 5.4.16-X` into the RHEL channel official, this version comes with the best Red Hat support.

You will install the php base distribution, with a best Red Hat support during all the life cycle of your Red Hat Entreprise Linux distribution.

Alternatively, if you have a registered RHEL7, you can use the Red Hat Software Collections Linux (RHSCL). It is a specific channel provided by Red Hat, it is different of "SCL" which is not supported by Red Hat (for CentOS by example). Mind you, these packets involve a short life cycle and an upgrade even if Red Hat gives 2 to 3 years. But the security fix is more shy than in main stream distribution RHEL7 cycle (packet php)... If you choose it, the best is to schedule upgrade all 1 year and half from your applications toward the last php rhscl version (with some king of integrations (major version php change...)

But, this collection is almost supported up to a certain point by Red Hat (by Remi for packaging too but with official red hat support (ticket, upgrade  security fix and bug fix in theory (in pratical, less than main stream php packet but CVE ok but only if Red Hat wants not mandatory like main stream, you always should to go in the last RHSCL version to be certain of equivalent support with the main stream distribution packet ). These RHSCL packets comes in addition (you can be able to have several versions (one follow the standard Red Hat version and an another for example).

For RHSCL, may need to initiate a special request for it at support Red Hat.

After you should be able to use in `root`:

For RH Content Delivery Network:

```
subscription-manager repos --list | grep rhscl 
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-variant-rhscl-7-rpms
```

For RH Network:

```
rhn-channel --available-channels
rhn-channel --add --channel=channel_name
yum install rh-php70
```

or better (if your application is compatible):

```
yum install rh-php71
```

To see the other component `rh-php7X`:

```
yum list available rh-php7X-\*
```

after:

```
yum install pkg-name
```

In PHP7.X with RHSCL, you can install (don't forget the components php module if you need):
 -> PHP 7.0.10  rh-php70    A release of PHP 7.0 with PEAR 1.10, enhanced language features and performance improvement.
-> PHP 7.1.8 [a]    rh-php71    A release of PHP 7.1 with PEAR 1.10, APCu 5.1.8, and enhanced language features.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, an installation not clean is already present. Not clean in the way of no support by Red Hat.

Some package comes from another channel, desinstall this package.

You will find it for example by:

```
rpm -qa | grep php
```

or:

```
yum list installed | grep php
yum remove pkg-name
```

To set it clean, you can replace it by RHSCL but if you can use the main stream, it is the best for the all life of the server (it depends on your application prerequisite...)